# Send broadcast message to 100K subscribers using ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, chat, publish-subscribe, ejabberd

I am creating PubSub like messaging application in which all subscribers of particular channel will get the message if publishers sends to the channel moreover 100k is the maximum subscriber count.
using ejabberd may I know the possibility of performance i.e can ejabberd handle 100k subscribers and will able to send message to all ?

Answer (score 0):

Performance depends on many elements. Payload size, push frequency, node configuration, type of online clients connection (slow / fast), machine specification.

However, you should be able to reach that level, indeed.